# Prove or disprove convexity

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am dealing with the following function  $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, how can I prove or disprove the convexity of the following function?
$$f(x)=\left\|x-\frac{Ax}{\langle x,b\rangle}\right\|_2$$
Where $A$ is a constant matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $b$ a constant vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Thanks.

Comment: A function is convex, if $\forall t\in[0,1]$ and all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ it holds that $f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$.
Just start with $f(tx+(1-t)y)$ and try to get to the expression on the right hand side of what  I just wrote, only by reformulating and estimating.

Comment: @MichaelGrant ,  right, I forgot to add the norm

Answer (score 0):

It's quite obvious this is not convex. After all, it is undefined whenever $\langle b, x \rangle = 0$. So its domain is the *complement* of that hyperplane, and therefore a non-convex set. All convex functions have convex domains, so this is definitely non-convex.

I really can't see a way to define the domain of this function in a sensible way that preserves convexity. I suppose you could require $\langle b, x \rangle > 0$, but do you really want to do that?

Even if you do I still doubt this function is convex. Convexity is what I personally call a *fragile* property. It's the *exception*, not the rule. Even when you take known convex functions and combine them together, you must do so according to specific rules, or you are likely to produce a nonconvex result. So for instance, in this case, the ratio $Ax/\langle x, b\rangle$ is a dead giveaway.